# Git rebase: finding the "next" commit to be rebased?

Tags: git, version-control, git-rebase

We have two branches in Git, `master` and `develop`. `master` is being updated constantly by a partner group, and I am constantly rebasing our `develop` branch onto `master`, something like this:

```
#(on develop)
$ git pull --rebase origin master #1
$ git rebase origin/develop       #2
$ git push origin develop         #3
```

…but yesterday someone from the partner group committed onto `master` without a proper e-mail address, so I encounter a problem by step `#2`:

```
git rebase origin/develop
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: <...>
<...>
Patch does not have a valid e-mail address.
```

and `git status` shows:

```
$ git status
# Not currently on any branch.
# You are currently rebasing.
#   (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")
#
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

What I have done is skip the commits without address with `git rebase --skip`, then cherry-pick these commits back after the rebase. But I wonder is this the proper way to do it? Can I cherry-pick the commit directly in-place, without skipping it? If yes, how do I actually find out this problematic commit (without looking it up in `git log`), as it is basically the *next* commit that are to be rebased onto the top of the current commit, so git must somehow knows which one it is…?

Comment: You did a rather brutal history rewriting with what you describe, it definitely isn't "the right way". And fixing up that problematic commit locally will also be history rewriting, also bad... as a last resort, OK. But better get the party doing the email-less commiting clean up their act, and have them fix up the mess they created as punishment.

Comment: @vonbrand thanks for the comment, we did give up this rebase-rebase strategy after a while and resorted to simply merging the master branch to develop. And yes, I ended up with asking the remote group to fix the empty email. Still, I was wondering... where does Git know which is the next commit to be rebased?

Answer (score 2):

You can try all the suggestions in [Change the author and committer name and e-mail of multiple commits in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750172/change-the-author-of-a-commit-in-git/33137355#33137355)

or you can add an `-i` in there to keep going (useful if you have a persistent auto-tooling commit issue or just want keep going and let someone else to fix their problem eventually)

So, when I get

```
> git rebase master
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Patch does not have a valid e-mail address.
```

I do `git rebase --abort`, and then

```
> git rebase master -i
Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/mybranch.
```

*This is true for git 2.1.4.*

Obviously, it comes up with a rebase list to edit, but you just save unedited that and go on your way.

And yes, it commits it with the "original author <>"